# Linux Console manipulating functions

Tags: c++, c, linux, console-application

Are there linux console (/terminal) equivalents for these WinAPI functions:

```
GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo // for getting cursor position
SetConsoleCursorPosition // for setting cursor position
SetConsoleWindowInfo // for resizing console window or hiding cursor
ReadConsoleOutputCharacter // for reading the character at some position
ReadConsoleOutputAttribute // for reading color info of the character at some position
WriteConsoleOutputAttribute // for changing color info of the character at some position
```

?

Comment: You need a terminal library. The standard choice is `ncurses`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [NCurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/)

> **for getting cursor position**

```
~$ echo -e "\033[6n"
```

> **for resizing console window**

```
wmctrl -r "Mozilla Firefox" -e <G>,<X>,<Y>,<W>,<H>
```

Comment: You have a funny title for your console windows

Answer (score 1):

There are almost all controls in

http://ispltd.org/mini_howto:ansi_terminal_codes

and

http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php

and

http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html

they can be run with `cout<<`